# how can i use variable in where condition ( in clause) in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-model

I am trying to filter user records from `user` table. I have a `user_id` string like e.g. 7,8,9, its working fine when I put that `user_id` string directly in when condition like this

```
 $model =  User::find()
            ->select(['id','username','first_name','last_name','image','year','city'])
            ->distinct(true)
            ->where(['IN','id',[ 7,8,9 ]])
            ->asArray()
            ->all();
```

but when I pass this `user_id` string in a variable, its show me only one record,

```
     $userFiltr = ArrayHelper::getColumn($result,'user_id');
     $user_id =  implode(',',$userFiltr); // $user_id return 7,8,9

     $model =  User::find()
        ->select(['id','username','first_name','last_name','image','year','city'])
        ->where(['IN','id',[ $user_id ]]) // when is user this variable $user_id, then query return only one result, white if i put 7,8,9 directly in where(['IN','id',[ 7,8,9 ]]) it return correct result  
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

problem is that when is user this variable $user_id, then query return only one result, white if i put 7,8,9 directly in where(['IN','id',[ 7,8,9 ]]) it return correct result .

**how can i use variable in where condition like where(['IN','id',[ $user_id ]])**
please help,thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `$userFiltr` is already an **array**, pass it to `where`:

```
$userFiltr = ArrayHelper::getColumn($result,'user_id');

$model = User::find()
    ->select(['id','username','first_name','last_name','image','year','city'])
    ->where(['IN','id',$userFiltr])
    ->asArray()->all();
```